# counting all the words matching the pattern in sql server records

Tags: sql-server, regex

I'm trying to count all the words in sql records having the following pattern

example:

[stackoverflow]

[stackexchange]

[control]

How to perform this in sql server.

I can able to count the known words, but how to count all the occurrences of words with pattern **[ ]**

Helps much appreciated

Comment: From a table. Or from entire database.??

Comment: people who are downvoting can explain the reason. So that i can improve my question. (I think i will expect the comment like "post your trying")

Comment: what pattern work contained inside [] ??

Comment: I have tried in excel to count words

Comment: Follow the pattern he follow to ask a question 
:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27125489/dynamic-pivot-table

Answer (score 0):

The SQL 'delimits' the special character with square brackets, telling the engine to treat it as a normal literal character instead of a character with special meaning. Check here for more info.

```
CREATE TABLE #test
  (
     a VARCHAR(50)
  )

INSERT INTO #test
VALUES      ('[stackoverflow]'),
            ('[stackoverflow]'),
            ('[stackexchange]'),
            ('[control]'),
            ('control')

SELECT a,
       Count(a)
FROM   #test
WHERE  a LIKE '%[[]%]%'
GROUP  BY a
```

Comment: I'm looking for answer to count individual words which satisfies patterns and their count

Comment: I want to count each and every word having this pattern

Comment: @PandiyanCool - yes bro that is what it is doing else say whats wrong in my output

Answer (score 0):

USE the pattern `('[[]%]')` to get count for words start and end with `'[]'`

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM YourTable WHERE SearchColumn  LIKE ('[[]%]')
```

Comment: I'm looking for answer to count individual words which satisfies patterns and their count

Comment: i DIDN'T GET YOU. Give an examble

Comment: @PandiyanCool - You are not clear with your requirements

Comment: I have lots of words having this patterns. I want to count all the words and their count

Comment: What happen if you post sample data and their related output.///

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> SELECT SUM(column_name REGEXP '^\\[.*\\]') from table_name;
```

should do the thing for you

Comment: MS sql solution please